# Sending http POST Request from Java client to WCF REST C#

Tags: java, c#, wcf

I do know that there are so many blogs and questions about this type of communication between two different languages by leveraging HTTP protocol. However, after reviewing relevant content on the web, I realized that one can't easily find a straightforward approach to achieve this type of communication. Consider the following scenario:

My java application takes a file of any type, convert it to a byte array (file size is large >3MB), the application can request a WCF REST (webHttpBinding) service, therefore it must use direct web request, in effect, the java application will receive a stream and start buffering the file content, send the stream to the WCF with at least a param (querystring field) to indicate the file type, Now the WCF service has to read the stream and reconstruct the file on the server side. hence the WCF would have to offer the following at least:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PostFileStream/{extension}")]
void PostFileStream(string ext,Stream file);
```

my question is twofold:

1) the bytes in the posted stream from Java to C# obviously are in different representation than the byte representation of C#, how to solve that efficiently?

**Note:** Serializing the byte array in the java side into string with Base64 and sending string post to C#, then inverse back to bytes on the c# side  **is in fact naive**, at least from my humble opinion, because there are a lot of complexity overheads especially with large files such as videos and scanned books, that require reading the entire file, converting large number of bytes back and forth on both sides

2) is there any programmer out there that can post **neat** and **efficient** sample of how to post bytes array (java) to WCF Rest service (C#), so that it can be a reference for those programmers who want to achieve java-C# Introp?

**Note:** My request to supply a sample doesn't have to be detailed but at least it will be very kind of some expert to highlight the guidelines of achieving such communication architecture.

Comment: That is what web services are for. Not sure what you are asking here?

Comment: I specified WCF Rest not SOAP-based services, second you can't post java byte array and expect to collect the same array in c# due to the signed byte array problem in java

Comment: Encode the data in Base64 on java side.

Comment: please read Q1 note